# How to avoid spam using bad words by duplicate characters?

Tags: php, regex

As you know, there is a common code to replace bad words:

```
$badwords = array('bad', 'very bad');
$string = str_replace($badwords, "***", $string);
```

But what if spammers duplicate some of characters? like "baaad" or "veery bad".

Comment: You'll quickly find yourself falling into a few clbuttic traps if you go down that path: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clbuttic/info .  Once you've identified a spammer, isn't better to hide their posts completely rather than censor specific words?

Comment: Yes, it is better to ban the spammer but what can i do with someone that creating multiple account? Most of our users have not static IP.

Comment: Consider 3rd party spam detection like http://antispam.typepad.com/

Comment: Do you know any code or class to help me on this issue? (filtering badwords)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm using PHP's [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php). If the word only needs one edit to become a bad word, then it could be a *possible* spam word with duplicate characters.